# Is there a way to have Mobile Number and Home Telephone Number in Billing address step?

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, billing

I wanted to add an additional field or remove the "Fax" field in Magento Onepage checkout.

Has anyone had to do something similar?

If anyone could share with me how I can change or add these fields so they they appear in Customer account page, `Sales_Order/View` page and invoices etc I would be very thankful.

Comment: refer to this **http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6**
or
**http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields**
It shows how you can add a field to the registration (Customer Account) form.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is definitely renaming `Fax` field into `Mobile`. To do so create (or edit if exists) `locale/en_US/translate.csv` file of your theme and add the following line:

```
"Fax","Mobile"
```

If you have different locale then English you have to create a directory with your locale code instead of `en_US`.

Answer (score 1):

There are the basic step to remove the unnecessary fields from the one page checkout. Just delete the following template file.

1./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

2./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml

But, it would be better to setting up & editing a new templates via layout XML rather than to changes on the core template.

Check this for a help:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
           <action method="set Template"><template>new/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>       
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.shipping">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>new/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
  </layout>
```